# Spring boot - exclude group of config classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot so sorry if this is too basic. My code takes a lot of time to build. I figured out that it's because Spring is loading a lot of config files that are not really needed.

My main file :

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
public class MySystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(MySystem.class, args);
    }
}
```

I tried using *@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {classes to exclude})* but the unused classes imported by Spring boot on build time are too much to include here individually, there are hundreds of them. Is there a way to exclude unused config files in batch or in group? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Auto configuration will only check if it needs to load configurations and load them only if they're needed. For example if you have a JDBC driver on classpath then it will load JPA configuration. If you don't want to load autoconfiguration classes then don't use it. You can use simple `@Configuration` on your class.

Comment: I guess *@Configuration* will just let the Spring system know that this is a Config class, yes? Then how will i configure the needed beans with this annotation? If i remove *@EnableAutoConfiguration* i get an error as the needed beans are not configured now.

Comment: You can add `@ComponentScan` to let Spring know which packages to scan for the beans.